# Problems with finding minimum polynomial of each element in Galois Field

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

The field GF(4) is obtained by extending the field F2 by the root of the polynomical x^2+x+1.
I found that field elements are {0,1,x,x+1}. Now I'm struggling with finding the order and minimum polynomial of each element. Could you help me a little?
I tried to find order of each element.
|0| = 1
|1| = 1
|x| = 3
|x+1| = 3
Are these answers correct?
And what is the minimum polynomial for each element? How to find?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). How did you determine the orders, and in which group? In the group $(\Bbb F_4,+)$, the element $x$ has order $2$, because $x+x=0$.